# insert data in rows based on conditional value in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a log file (.txt) containing the following data structure:

**ID-Number 1**

value 1

value 2

**ID-Number 2**

value 1

value 2

value 3

**ID-Number 3**

value 1

I'm expecting to have the following
every **ID-Number** could have multiple **values**. I need to put each **value** beside it's **ID-Number** like the following:

ID-Number 1,value 1,value 2

ID-Number 2,value 1,value 2,value 3

ID-Number 3,value 1

Comment: do you have id number or how you differentiate id number with value?

Comment: the string 'ID-Number' is static in each 'ID-Number <int>' field. the integer number is the one that changed every time.

Comment: Why the `pandas` tag? Do you need a pandas dataframe out of this file?

Comment: My goal is to store the final output into CSV or excel format. hence, I added pandas perhaps i will use one of pandas functions to store my data on **df** and then organize it as per the above structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    newline = []
    res = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if 'ID-Number' in line:
            if newline:
                res.append(','.join(newline))
            newline = [line]
            continue
        newline.append(line)
res.append(','.join(newline))
```

Comment: removing `res.append(','.join(newline))` worked for me thank you @galaxyan